# Why is my Chrome Extension grayed out?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

#### Problem

A chrome extension I wrote is grayed out, and I can't figure out why.

#### Context

I wrote and submitted a Chrome Extension called [Pull Favors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pull-favors/eekfnkibgmemnnbbmdglmjabjdfdjglj) to the Chrome webstore.

It uses the CSS `order` property to sort and group GitHub Pull-Requests in a logical way.

The other day I noticed that several of my extensions were grayed out, and 'blocked'--meaning they no longer work. One of these was Pull Favors.

According to this [support article](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2811969?hl=en):

> If you see a message saying "Extensions Disabled," it's because Chrome has turned off one or more of your extensions to keep your data safe while you're browsing the Internet. The extensions that Chrome turned off either didn't come from the Chrome Web Store or were installed without your permission."

My extension is [published in the Chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pull-favors/eekfnkibgmemnnbbmdglmjabjdfdjglj) and was certainly installed with my permission.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail.

I suspect there's something wrong with my extension (since a few other extensions seem to still work), but I can't figure out what it is or find anything about it on the internet.

What's going on?

#### Research

Chrome seems to have implemented a [new policy](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) in November 2013, which has caused [some uproar](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2yTVWdfC4Gg) in the community, which prevents Windows users from installing extensions from outside the web store.

I'm not sure why this is affecting me, as I'm an OS X user and, as I said, my extension is distributed through the webstore.

Answer (score 39):

Add `browser_action.default_icon` in your `manifest.json` file

```
{
  ...

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-32.png"
  },

  ...
}
```

---

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Worked for me (Chrome 52). Be careful if you do not set the popup source nothing will happen when the user clicks your extension icon.

Comment: @Jared, what did you mean by `not set the popup source` ?

Comment: If you don't set `"default_popup"` under `"browser_action"` when you click your extension icon nothing will happen. Normally a menu appears where you can disable the extension, etc.

Comment: also, "page_action":{...} may be more appropriate if the extension will only be active on certain websites (e.g. " matches: {...}")

Comment: Doing this removed the default dropdown that my extension had, primarily my "options" page option. Is there a way to keep both?

Comment: now (with v3 mandatory) use "action" instead of "browser_action"

Answer (score 8):

In one of the last couple updates, they did something weird with the extensions that now makes all enabled extensions show up in either the toolbar or in the menu. In your case, the extension icon is grayed out because you don't even use a browser action or a page action, so it is just showing the icon. So it isn't disabled, just doesn't have an active state so is grayed out.

A quick search doesn't seem to turn up a blog post about it, but if you right click on the icon you can hide it in the menu.