# Chrome Extension icon not having color

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just create my first Chrome extension. My extension's icon shows correctly (with color) in the extension manager page:
[image: Icon with color]

But Chrome shows a grayscale version of my icon in the extension bar:
[image: Icon without color]

Here's the manifest of my extension:

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/chromereload.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "contentSettings"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/contentscript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ]
}
```

What can I do to make Chrome show my icon with color next to the address bar?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Chrome Extension grayed out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049472/why-is-my-chrome-extension-grayed-out)

Comment: @StefanoNardo although the icon is grayed out, this is a different issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is odd behaviour, I don't know why it's happening but I know the solution: you should be using `default_icon` instead of `icon`:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
}
```

Note that the icon needs to be 19x19 or 38x38 pixels.

You've defined the larger icon correctly though so you could leave that as is.

See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) for more info.

Comment: This works. Thanks!! (SO does not allow me to mark your answer as correct  for some reason)

Comment: @ThangCoder glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience and on Noam's answer I'm tempted to say that it is because your extension doesn't have a `"browser_action"` defined. In other words: its icon is there to show it is installed, but it doesn't do anything, so it had its colors removed.

This is just a guess not confirmed by any documentation or test.

Answer (score 0):

The other responses are working, but only for `manifest_version <= 2`. for version 3, instead of `browser_action` just `action`. for more details on other keywords check [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/)