# Page action button icon grayed out on URL where content script runs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a Chrome extension which contains the following lines inside the *manifest.json*
(I only removed name and description meta data):

```
"permissions":[],
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "run_at":"document_start",
        "matches":[
            "https://www.amazon.de/*",
            "https://www.amazon.it/*",
            "https://www.amazon.co.uk/*",
            "https://www.amazon.es/*",
            "https://www.amazon.fr/*"
        ],
        "js":[
           "jquery-1.10.2.min.js", "schnapperama.js"
        ]
    }
],
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"options_page": "options/index.html",
"icons":{
    "16":"options/img/schnapper16.png",
    "48":"options/img/schnapper48.png",
    "128":"options/img/schnapper128.png"
},
"page_action":{
    "default_icon":"options/img/schnapper38.png"
},
"web_accessible_resources":[],
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  https://www.amazon.de; object-src 'self'",
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  https://www.amazon.it; object-src 'self'",
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  https://www.amazon.fr; object-src 'self'",
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  https://www.amazon.es; object-src 'self'",
"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  https://www.amazon.co.uk; object-src 'self'"
```

As you can see, it has the `page_action` set and also some `matches` entered.

If I go onto any of those sites mentioned in `matches` my script is successfully run. Nonetheless, the icon for my extension stays gray on those pages.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call [`chrome.pageAction.show()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show) in order for your page action button to be active (icon not greyed out). Showing (enabling) the pageAction button not automatically associated with the pages on which your content script runs.

From Chrome's [pageAction page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) (emphasis mine):

> You make a page action appear and be grayed out using the [pageAction.show](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show) and [pageAction.hide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-hide) methods, respectively. **By default, a page action appears grayed out.** When you show it, you specify the tab in which the icon should appear. The icon remains visible until the tab is closed or starts displaying a different URL (because the user clicks a link, for example).

From the way that you have architected your extension, your best bet is pobably to have your content script send a message, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`, to your background script to tell it to show your page action icon for the associated tab.

It could be something like:

background script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.type === 'showPageAction') {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});
```

content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'showPageAction'});
```

Answer (score -3):

Add browser_action.default_icon in your manifest.json file.

Here is the answer!

[Why is my Chrome Extension grayed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049472/why-is-my-chrome-extension-grayed-out)

Comment: Your answer, and the one that you linked, don't really have anything to do with this question. In this question, the OP is using a page action button, not a browser action button and does assign a `default_icon`.